# Update database with html link click using ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've read through a number of similar questions and tried my hand at putting it to work on my website, but it is not working (when you click the link there is no response on the console and the database is not updated).

Here's what I want to do: I want users to rate a comment `+1` by clicking an icon next to the comment. I want that to update my mysql `comment_table` column called `rating` with `rating+1`. When I do it without AJAX (ie, just set the form action to a `php page?id=10`) it works fine. I can't get the AJAX to update the database though.

My main page with the comment:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="updateRating(1,<?php echo $thisperspective_row['id']; ?>)" alt="UPVOTE" id="upvote_<?php echo $thisperspective_row['id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
```

The javascript below that link:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function updateRating(rating, id){

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "rating.php",
    mode: "vote",
    rating: rating,
    id: <?php echo $thisperspective_row['id']; ?>,
    success: function(response) {
     console.log(response); 
    }
});
return false; // Prevent the browser from navigating to the-script.php
                };
</script>
```

and my rating.php file is

```
<?php
require_once('connectiontodatabase.php'); 

/* simple comment up and down voting script */
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
$rating = $_GET['rating'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($mode=="vote")
    {
    // The name of the 
    $cookie = "nameofmycookie".$id;  
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) 
        { 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-warning"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button> Sorry You have already rated this comment within the last 14 days.</div>'; 
        } 
    else 
        {
        $expiry = 1209600 + time();  // 14 day expiry
        setcookie ($cookie, "voted", $expiry);
        mysql_query ("UPDATE comment_table SET rating = rating+$rating WHERE id=$id", $connection);
        }
    }

?>
```

The php runs fine and all the variables are listed properly when I view the source. However, when I click the link, there is no response at all and the console does not output the response. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Ajax you need to send data like this, `data: {mode: "vote", rating: rating, id: id}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should change the way you are detecting the click event. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styphon/2HRrt/). Then secondly you need to pass all the variables through in one [JSON string](http://www.json.org/) using the data option. Your code should look something like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up clickable" 
    data-rating="1" 
    data-id="<?php echo $thisperspective_row['id']; ?>"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.clickable').on('click', function() {
        var data = {
            mode: "vote",
            rating: $(this).data('rating'),
            id: $(this).data('id')
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'rating.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Styphon. Your solution worked when I made one change to your suggested code:
Instead of typing `$.ajax(function() {` I typed `$.ajax({`

Comment: @GK79 Yea, for most jQuery you have function() in there, but not for ajax. I must have added it in out of habit hehe. Updated my answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

First off all, check that you are loading jQuery, then use this code

```
function updateRating(rating, id){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "rating.php",
    mode: "vote",
    data: { rating: rating, id: id },
    success: function(response) {
     console.log(response); 
    }
  });
return false; // Prevent the browser from navigating to the-script.php
};
```

is working for me.
note that I removed ` inside Ajax, since you are already sending the params in the function, also to send params you have to use **data:**, you can see more examples here [Ajax jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not advanced enough in jquery to understand why the onClick event for a link was not able to trigger the function (check out @Styphon's fiddle). It did not work for me so I decided to go with the solution above by Styphon. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Thanks, also I would recommend you to add `mysql_real_escape_string()` to any **GET** or **POST** that you get from users.

You can see more about that function in here. [link](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)